# Бесконечно обновляется сайт Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, бот, chromedriver

Пишу бота для мониторинга свободных слотов VFS Global, нашел проект на [GitHUb](https://github.com/hnavidan/VFSBot.git), но он не проходил cloudflare, как я понял, на stack overflow нашел вопрос, в котором был тоже бот, но там с капчей проблем не было, я добавил часть кода себе и теперь сайт бесконечно перезагружается, хотя причин по коду для этого нет

```
def login(self, update, context):
    self.browser.get((self.url))
    
    if "You are now in line." in self.browser.page_source:
       update.message.reply_text("You are now in queue.")

    WebDriverWait(self.driver, 20).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//iframe[@title="reCAPTCHA"]')))
    recaptcha_iframe = self.driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//iframe[@title="reCAPTCHA"]')
    solver = RecaptchaSolver(driver=self.driver)
    solver.click_recaptcha_v2(iframe=recaptcha_iframe)

    email_input = self.driver.find_element(By.ID, "mat-input-0")
    email_input.clear()
    email_input.send_keys(self.email_str)
    time.sleep(2)

    password_input = self.driver.find_element(By.ID, "mat-input-1")
    password_input.clear()
    password_input.send_keys(self.pwd_str)
    time.sleep(1)
    password_input.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
```